# OSX pthreads: cthread_set_errno_self segfault

Tags: c++, macos, pthreads, segmentation-fault

I am having a small problem every now and again where my program segfaults immediately after creating a new thread.

The new thread has a backtrace like:

```
Thread 24 Crashed:
0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8ea3c358 _spin_lock$VARIANT$mp + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8e9e9f25 _pthread_exit + 55
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8e9ea27d pthread_exit + 30
3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8e9a022b cthread_set_errno_self + 76
4   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x00007fff87cd701d cerror + 33
5   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8e9e88bf _pthread_start + 335
6   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff8e9ebb75 thread_start + 13
```

The state of the CPU at the time of the crash is as follows:

```
Thread 24 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000001  rcx: 0x00007fff87cd55ba  rdx: 0x00000000ffffffff
  rdi: 0x0000000101f0e010  rsi: 0x0000000000000001  rbp: 0x0000000101f0de70  rsp: 0x0000000101f0de08
   r8: 0x0000000101f0e010   r9: 0x0000000000000001  r10: 0x00007fff87cd5ca6  r11: 0x0000000000000202
  r12: 0x0000000000000032  r13: 0x0000000101f0e000  r14: 0x0000000101f0e000  r15: 0x0000000007010101
  rip: 0x00007fff8ea3c358  rfl: 0x0000000000010286  cr2: 0x0000000101f0e010
Logical CPU: 0
```

`cr2` == `rdi` and `r8`; without seeing the actual code for these I can only hazard a guess as to why this address is invalid.

This seems to be an issue in `errno`, which (AFAIK) is thread-local storage?

Is it possible this is due to heap or other memory corruption elsewhere in the program? This particular issue is exceptionally hard to reproduce but it'd be great to resolve the issue if at all possible.

Comment: Having looked at http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.25/threads/cprocs.c, it looks like this particular issue stems from the thread being cancelled. I'm not entirely sure why cancelling the thread would cause it to crash like this... but perhaps pthread_destroy() has been called or something in the meantime.

Comment: Why not show the sources?